# Print only a part of the result of a command

Tags: linux, shell, command, centos7

I am trying to obtain the status of a httpd service with Centos 7.
I want to know if i can print only the value of Active, that in this example is inactive (dead)

This is the command that i am using:

```
 [root@localhost ~]# service httpd status | grep Active
```

This is the result of that command.

```
 Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  httpd.service
       Active: inactive (dead)
```

This is the output that i a want: inactive (dead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
/bin/systemctl status  httpd.service | grep -o "\w*ctive "
```